# MonoTouch Trial adaquate to submit to App Store?

Tags: ios, ios4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am enrolled in the Apple Developer Program ($99/year) and I have the trial (free) version of MonoTouch.  Am I able to submit MonoTouch apps to the App Store with what I have now or do I need to get one of the paid versions of MonoTouch first?  I know that one of the differences between the free version of MonoTouch vs. the paid versions is the ability to run your apps on your iOS hardware during development but doesn't the Apple Developer Program get you some kind of ability to do this as well?  Just a bit confused.

Note:  If this belongs in another StackExchange site, please let me know and I will move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting confused...

MonoDevelop is free, its MonoTouch that has the trail/paid versions. Basically you'll need to purchase either MonoTouch Professional or MonoTouch Enterprise in order to get your iPhone app into the App store as the trail version only allows to run the app in the simulator.

http://monotouch.net/Store - see first paragraph

EDIT: Being part of the Apple Dev Program provides you with a Developer Certificate which allows you to upload applications to the App Store (generally, be it obj-c based or other) whereas the paid versions of MonoTouch provides you with the mechanism to get your application in a state where it can be deployed to a device and the app store - and also a cunning way of generating money. Because whose going to develop iPhone apps without a desire to distribute them ;)

Comment: Thanks. I WAS confused, that's why I said that I was confused. :)

Answer (score 1):

without a license, you can only run MonoTouch apps in the simulator.  You cannot deploy them to a device or the App Store.

Comment: Jason, I purchased MonoTouch professional license for one year. Is it possible to use that license after one year?

Comment: I believe that MT will still work, but you will not be able to install any new updates with an expired license.

Comment: So If i was used MonoTouch 4.2.2 for licensed version means I can't use next updating version(like 4.2.3). right?